# Mugsy error: Can't find species II dna at output/software/mugsy_x86-64-v1r2.3/mugsy line 501

Tags: sequence-alignment, software-usage

I have installed [mugsy](http://mugsy.sourceforge.net/) in order to create a multiple genome alignment and a phylogenetic tree of several species of nematodes. The following command successfully pulls out the help:

```
output/software/mugsy_x86-64-v1r2.3/mugsy -h
```

To test that the software is installed correctly and that I am using it correctly, I ran the following alignment between the Wormbase sequence and the Ensembl sequence of the *C. elegans* genome:

```
output/software/mugsy_x86-64-v1r2.3/mugsy  --directory /.../project/output/software/mugsy_x86-64-v1r2.3/ --prefix mygenomes output/genome/celegans/ref/wormbase/seq/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS263.genomic.fa output/genome/celegans/ref/ensembl/seq/celegans.fa
```

I get the following output:

```
Parsing sequences for c_elegans  num_seqs:7
Parsing sequences for celegans  num_seqs:1
Can't find species II dna at output/software/mugsy_x86-64-v1r2.3/mugsy line 501.
```

The headers of the wormbase sequences are:

```
>I
>II
>III
>IV
>V
>X
>MtDNA
```

and the headers of the ensembl sequences are:

```
>I dna:chromosome chromosome:WBcel235:I:1:15072434:1 REF
>II dna:chromosome chromosome:WBcel235:II:1:15279421:1 REF
>III dna:chromosome chromosome:WBcel235:III:1:13783801:1 REF
>IV dna:chromosome chromosome:WBcel235:IV:1:17493829:1 REF
>MtDNA dna:chromosome chromosome:WBcel235:MtDNA:1:13794:1 REF
>V dna:chromosome chromosome:WBcel235:V:1:20924180:1 REF
>X dna:chromosome chromosome:WBcel235:X:1:17718942:1 REF
```

Maybe this line:
    `Parsing sequences for celegans  num_seqs:1` should make me worry. Why does mugsy think there is only one sequence in that genome? Why do I get the following error and how can I fix it?:

```
Can't find species II dna at output/software/mugsy_x86-64-v1r2.3/mugsy line 501.
```

I am working on a GNU/Linux platform.